# How do you filter duplicate columns in a dataframe based on a value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, duplicates

I would like to filter duplicate rows in a DataFrame according to columns "NID", "Lact" and code when the column "Code" = 10.

The following data provides example data

```
data_list = {'NID': {1: '1', 2: '1', 3: '1', 4: '1', 5: '2', 6: '2', 7: '1'},
 'Lact': {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 1},
            'Code': {1: 10, 2: 0, 3: 10, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 10, 7: 0}}
```

The DataFrame appears below

```
  NID Lact  Code
1   1   1   10
2   1   1   0
3   1   1   10
4   1   2   0
5   2   2   0
6   2   2   10
7   1   1   0
```

If I run the following filter to identify duplicates it identifies duplicate rows based on "NID", "Lact", and "Code"

```
df[(df.duplicated(['NID', 'Lact', 'Code'], keep=False))]
```

The output is provided below

```
  NID Lact  Code
1   1   1   10
2   1   1   0
3   1   1   10
7   1   1   0
```

I would like to make this filter conditional on `Code = 10` as I would like to delete the first instance of duplicate rows when code = 10 but not when code is not equal to 10

Is there a way to add a condition for `Code == 10` to this filter?

Comment: How looks expected ouput?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to keep all rows if Code is not equal to 10 but drop the first of duplicates otherwise, right? Then you could add that into the boolean mask:

```
cols = ['NID', 'Lact', 'Code']
out = df[~df.duplicated(cols, keep=False) | df.duplicated(cols) | df['Code'].ne(10)]
```

Output:

```
  NID  Lact  Code
2   1     1     0
3   1     1    10
4   1     2     0
5   2     2     0
6   2     2    10
7   1     1     0
```

Answer (score 0):

If need remove first duplicated row if condition `Code == 10` chain it with [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://%5Bandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with default `keep='first'` parameter and if need also filter all duplicates chain `m2` with `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
m1 = df['Code'].eq(10)
m2 = df.duplicated(['NID', 'Lact', 'Code'], keep=False)
m3 = df.duplicated(['NID', 'Lact', 'Code'])


df = df[(~m1 | m3) & m2]
print (df)
  NID  Lact  Code
2   1     1     0
3   1     1    10
7   1     1     0
```